# How to print HTML Response of node js request response

Tags: node.js

I am getting a response of node js request having options like URL methods and cookie but I am getting a response as an HTML with some script. While consoling the response, I am getting some encoded text and having buffer data. How I can print the response of HTML as it is i.e HTML in my response to the HTTP request.
.....................................
const https = require('https');
SearchById(Id)
{

const options = {}

```
  const req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      try{
        if(res)
        {
            console.log("response",res)// here i am getting json data
            res.on('data', d => {
              console.log("SearchById ",d);  // here i am getting  encoded text with buffer data
            })
        }
        else{
          console.log(`product with ${id} is not there`)
        }
      }
      catch(err)
      {
        console.log(err);
      }
  })

}
```

SearchById(777474)

Comment: assign it to a element of your DOM like a div for example

Comment: I want to fetch the id which is present in the response which is in HTML format.I need just an HTML response in my Editor. Is it possible?

Comment: you should clarify this in your question with explicit data and the best would be when you share your code. Its much better to show us what you did and want instead of when you describing it

Comment: What are you debugging? The nodejs program giving the html response, or the program receiving the response? If you explain your problem more thoroughly we can help you better. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I passed the options object with all requirements, I am getting response as  HTML and that is ok but in HTML body id is coming , I need to extract the id from the body of the HTML response